# Error float - Cambiar tipo de dato en migración Laravel

Tags: float, conversión-de-tipos, tipos

Estoy trabajando con el tipo **FLOAT** en Laravel y en mysql tengo **double(8,2)** me di cuenta que si introduzco números como por ejemplo 1000000 me indica el siguiente error:

> Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column

Bien hasta acá el problema es claro, pero mi pregunta se basa en que tipo de dato usar para manejar **DINERO** y de que manera es la forma más práctica ?

Yo haría lo siguiente:

```
php artisan make:migration alter_profiles_table --table=profiles

$table->dropColumn('dinero');
$table->bigInteger('dinero');
```

¿Si hago esto que pasará con los datos actuales?

```
   $table->float('precio_propiedad');
```

Pero tengo dudas si esto sirve para el manejo de dinero, debido a que el día de mañana podría haber decimales. Y también haría un string pero no podría manejar operaciones matemáticas para sacar estadísticas.

¿Por lo tanto que me recomiendan hacer?

Comment: Bien y el cambio me afecta a los datos actuales? tendría que hacer esto...$table->dropColumn('dinero');
$table->decimal('dinero'); ?? y por ultimo cuantos caracteres soporta sabes pregunto para poner |max:?? Gracias @BetaM !

Comment: Bueno muchas gracias...aun tengo la duda con los datos actuales cargados como flota los voy a perder no?

Comment: muchas gracias como califico tu respuesta? saludos